# module not importing in my views.py file

Tags: python, django, module, google-python-api

I am running a django site and am having issues with the Http module running in my views file. It's running in a python virtual environment and I have checked to ensure that all required packages are installed via the pip3 freeze command.
The module will import and run in another script file within the same environment just not my views.py file. When attempting to import the module in my views.py file I get the following error:

```
 [:error] [pid 2122] [remote 108.214.118.85:188] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Http'
```

The code on the script that is functioning properly is as follows:

```
import json
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build


scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('keyfile.json', scopes)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
caladmin = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)
events_query = caladmin.events().list(calendarId='calendarId').execute()

def get_events():
    if not events_query['items']:
        print('No upcoming events')

    events = events_query['items']
    print(events)
    return events


get_events()
```

Here is the code that is returning the above error:

```
import os
import json
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build
from django.shortcuts import render


def news(request):
    events = get_events()
    context = {'events':events}
    return render(request, 'district/about/news.html')

def get_events():
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('keyfile.json', scopes)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    caladmin = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http_auth)
    events_query = caladmin.events().list(calendarId='calendarId').execute()

    if not events_query['items']:
        print('No upcoming events')

    events = events_query['items']
    return events
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance. :)

Comment: You probably have a local file called httplib2.py. Rename it.

Comment: I just ran a search in the virtual environment for an httplib2.py file and found nothing.

Comment: Another way to check Daniel's Theory is to put `import httplib2; print(httplib2.__file__)` in each of your files to ensure that you're importing the same module in both places. Or use the `inspect` module to do the same thing.

Comment: I just checked the path that both are referencing via print(httplib2.__file__) and both are the same. Both are pointing to: /var/www/virtual_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py